# Setting up Google Analytics on a Single-Page website

Tags: google, analytics

I have added Google Analytics code to many websites but this time I created a website with a single page. I would like to be able to track analytics for each part of the page, e.g. #bio, #testimonials, etc.

Can someone please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Google has a guide for that in their Google Analytics documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to track eack click on a link I would suggest adding events for every link and button you wish to track in GA.

Then there is another option to add scroll tracking to see how far the visitor have scrolled and send events to GA based on how far down they have scrolled. There are pleny of examples of this on the web. You can of course combine these techniques as you see fit for your website.

It is even easier to implement this if you are using Google Tag Manager.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend following up these [google guidelines](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications), basically you need to create event listeners across the page for everything you wish to track.

To make your life easier you should use a plugin, like [this one found in GitHub](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack/blob/master/docs/plugins/event-tracker.md) and/or use Google Tag Manager (GTM) and follow available tutorial on the internet to setup your Tags.